# Why does $(x)$ generate $R$? The proof of $1 - rx$ is a unit $\iff x\in J$ where $J$ is Jacobson Radical

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, proof-explanation

Here is a sample proof from Dummit and Foote

> [image]

Why does some random element $x \in R - M$ (together with $M$) generate the whole ring? I think in this context $R$ is a commutative ring with $1$. But if $x$ is chosen such that it is a non unit, how can it generate $1$ for example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$M$ is by assumption a maximal ideal. $(x,M)$ is an ideal which contains it, and since $x\notin M$ the inclusion $M\subseteq (x,M)$ is proper. Since $M$ is maximal this implies $(x,M)=R$.

Comment: That's a good way to see it. Thanks. a new question just came up. How do we know the set generated by $M$ and $(x)$ is an ideal? Is it just $(M,x) = M + (x)?$

Comment: Just looked it up, they are indeed the same ideal.

Comment: will accept answer after the timer is up or latest tomorrow.

Comment: It is an ideal simply by definition. For a set $S\subseteq R$, by definition $(S)$ is the smallest (by inclusion) ideal in $R$ which contains $S$. Just like in vector spaces span($S$) is the smallest subspace which contains $S$. And yes, in our case we indeed have the equality $(x,M)=(x)+M$.

Comment: Sorry I keep popping with questions, but for the first line. it says "suppose $1 - rx$ is not a unit, then let some $M$ maximal ideal contain $ 1- rx$". How do we know we have such Maximal ideal to contain it?

Comment: @Hawk If $1-rx$ is not a unit, the principal ideal $(1-rx) \subsetneq R$ is a proper ideal. Hence it is contained in some maximal ideal, as every proper ideal is contained in a maximal one. This is proved using Zorn's Lemma.

Comment: Ah okay because if $1 - rx$ were a unit $u$,  then $1 = u^{-1}u \in u^{-1}(1 - rx) \subset (1 - rx)$ would not proper.

Comment: @Hawk The notation $(x,M)$ is a bit of abuse of notation. More properly, the ideal generated by $x$ and $M$ should be $(x)+M$. Also, in general $(r_1, \dots, r_n)=(r_1) + \cdots +(r_n)$; and similarly for any ideal (not just finitely generated).